# Html SignalR Chat overflow of chat box

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, overflow

I am creating a chat application with Group and Private messages,
I wanted to make it much like the facebook Messenger web application (http://messenger.com)

The problem I'm running into is getting the List of groups / users / profile / messages to have its own scroll bar and stop at the end of the page, same thing with the chat box on the messages page[image: This is what the page is looking like]

Everything outlined in green should have its own scroll bar and should not extend or push the other objects off the page

The users page, along with the groups and messages page all continue on past the end of the page with no scroll bar appearing.

Tools: Angular UI / SignalR / Bootstrap / ASP.Net MVC 5 C# w/ Razor

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <tabset>
        <tab>
           <tab-heading>Profile</tab-heading>
           <!--Content of tab goes here-->
        </tab>
        <tab>
            <tab-heading>Users</tab-heading>
            <div class="content">
                 <a ng-repeat="user in users">
                     <user-item profile="user"></user-item>
                 </a>
            </div>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="chat-box">
        <a ng-repeat="message in messages">
            <message-item message="message"></message-item>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
     height: 100%;
     width:100%;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper{
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Update:

After more looking around I came across VH and VW attributes to CSS heights / widths, I have tried multiple times with different combinations and nothing came out of it.
I don't want to set a height / width in pixels because it will be used on both mobile and desktop sites - preferably without writing multiple pages.

Is there any way to set the parent containers width & height using "something like" percentages and then use the percents on the child attributes as well.

If there is a valid CSS way to do this, I would prefer that over JavaScript as I have tried JavaScript before but it wasn't too elegant of a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the reason as to why it doesn't work.

Because I'm trying to get it to be the size of the screen and using percentages vs using hard typed heights, it requires that every wrapping div has a height and/or width attribute to it, then the last div (that needs to be scroll able) has the overflow-y attribute.

```
<body style="height:100%;width:100%;">
     <div style="height:100%;">
         <ul style="height:100%; overflow-y: auto;">
              <li ng-repeat="user in users">
                  <user-display user="user"></user-display>
              </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</body>
```

This is a basic example of what worked for me, mine was just a ton more stacked divs.

Answer (score 0):

Alec,
In order to make tab content scrollable you need to change the way it's displayed  using **display: block**; to display that as a block level element.

**content { display: block; }**

Comment: Adding Display: Block didn't do anything to make the content scrollable. Maybe I'm doing it wrong? I applied it to the content CSS class but that output was the same as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

**overflow-y: auto**;
This could be what you're looking for.
[JS Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5ucD3/461/)

```
$('.add').click(function(){    
  $("#mylist").append("<li>Test</li>");
  $('#mylist').animate({scrollTop: $('#mylist').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
});
```

Comment: I can see how I can implement this in such a manner as for it to work, but this doesn't really address the question... You see overflow-y doesn't work when setting it to auto or to scroll, plus I'm using angular for the population of the list.